# Database query skipping leading digit in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database

I'm writing a Java program that utilizes Derby for managing a vehicle database. The unique identifier for each vehicle is a 17 character VIN. For this specific query, my desired result is to get the make, for example, 'Ford':

```
SELECT make FROM VehicleData where vin = 1HSRDG2RXJH584627
```

I get this error:

```
----- SQLException -----
  SQL State:  42X01
  Error Code: 30000
  Message:    Syntax error: Encountered "HSRDG2RXJH584627" at line 1, column 43.
```

It seems that the leading '1' in the VIN in the WHERE clause is getting ignored. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the VIN in quotes. In Java, the quotes have to be escaped:

```
"SELECT make FROM VehicleData where vin = \"1HSRDG2RXJH584627\""
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the quotes if you use single quotes within the SQL string. That's more standard SQL anyway. `"SELECT make FROM VehicleData where vin = '1HSRDG2RXJH584627'"`